# is it possible to edit an object in an image using opencv in android?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, opencv

Im trying to edit an object in an image using opencv in android, say to change only the color of a tshirt which is an object in that image.

Is it possible and how it can be done??

Please help me.

Thanks and Regards,
Srinivasan

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but a quick and dirty solution would be:
Click into the object (t-shirt) and perform a floodfill in the color you want to. The t-shirt has to have closed contours, otherwise the floodfill won´t stop filling. I am trying to close the contours in my pictures at the moment, but I do not know how...